# Are all NP-complete languages log-space reducible to each other?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

NP-complete languages are reducible to each other in polynomial time. Does this mean that they are also log-space reducible to each other?

It seems as if this is true because in log-space, we can have polynomially many computations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete#Completeness_under_different_types_of_reduction) makes the following points:

1. It is unknown whether all NP-complete languages are NP-complete also with respect to logspace reductions.
2. However, "all known" NP-complete languages are NP-complete also with respect to logspace reductions.
3. There are some hints that a weaker class of reductions, AC<sup>0</sup> reductions, may result in a different notion of NP-completeness.